# Non linear, three way sum of table data

Tags: mysql, sql

My [table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dc39)

```
user_name     id      status          calls
===========================================
apple        21       BadAd             2
apple        21       Lead              5
apple        21       DNC               6
apple        21       pajs              2
orange       34       Lead              9
orange       34       disks             3
orange       34       BadAd             8
orange       34       pajs              5
```

My attempt

```
 SELECT sum(calls) FROM (SELECT y.calls, y.user_name, y.status FROM stats
 INNER JOIN
 (select user_name, status, sum(calls) as calls
 from stats WHERE status = ('BadAD', 'Lead', 'DNC')
 group by user_name, status) y
 ON y.user_name = stats.user_name
 GROUP BY y.status) w WHERE w.user_name = y.username
```

My problem: I am trying to add up the values from the `calls` field of rows that only contain a certain `status` field value (`WHERE status = ('BadAD', 'Lead', 'DNC')`) and has the same user_name. So it would look like this.

```
user_name     id      status          calls
===========================================
apple        21       BadAd             13           (BadAd 2 + Lead 5 + DNC 6)
orange       34       Lead              17           (etc..)
```

Comment: Do you mean `status IN ('BadAD', 'Lead', 'DNC')`?

Comment: The `status` in the result is not meaningful — at most it tells you that one of the statuses was of that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select user_name, id, min(status), sum (calls)
from yourtable
where status in  ('BadAD', 'Lead', 'DNC')
group by user_name, id
```